# Type inference error with inner join on multiple columns in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to join a single column from one table to 2 columns from another table using inner join but getting error as shown below :

My classes are defined as below :

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}

public class LeaveRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SentFromEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int SentToEmployeeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LeaveUpdateLogs> LeaveUpdateLogs { get; set; }
}

public class LeaveUpdateLogs 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset RequestedDate { get; set; }

    public int LeaveRequestId { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual LeaveRequest LeaveRequest { get; set; }
}
```

**Sql Query :**

```sql
    select SentFromEmployeeId,SentToEmployeeId,* from LeaveUpdateLogs l
    inner join LeaveRequest lr on l.LeaveRequestId = lr.Id
    inner join Employee e1 on e1.Id = lr.SentFromEmployeeId or e1.Id = lr.SentToEmployeeId
    where (l.RequestedDate >= '2021-11-01' and l.RequestedDate < '2021-11-16')
        and (e1.DepartmentId =100 or e2.DepartmentId = 100)
```

**Linq:**

```
var query = from l in context.LeaveUpdateLogs
            join e in context.Employee
            on new { l.LeaveRequest.SentFromEmployeeId, l.LeaveRequest.SentToEmployeeId }
            equals new { Id1 = e.Id, Id2 = e.Id } into j
            where  j.DepartmentId== 100
```

> Error : Type of expression in one of the join clause is
> incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'groupjoin'

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Why not just wire up navigation properties for the `SentFrom/ToEmployeeId` and then you can get EF to do the joins

Comment: @CaiusJard Currently the model is designed like this and I cant update it, so that's the issue

Comment: `new { l.LeaveRequest.SentFromEmployeeId, l.LeaveRequest.SentToEmployeeId }` if one or both of them are nullable or different type then the `Id` property on the other table you need to cast properties into correct type in the second anonymous object :`{ Id1 = (int?)e.Id, Id2 = (int?)e.Id }`

Comment: @Eldar Both SentFromEmployeeId and SentToEmployeeId  are not nullable

Comment: This does seem a bit odd; you want to know the list of all the leaves that a manager has approved for someone else or taken themselves? (It feels like two queries, not one.. Or if I was doing it in e.g. straight SQL I'd join Employee in twice, not OR it)

Comment: Also names should be equal?

Comment: @CaiusJard I want to get data for both "Sent" and "Received" request and only that either of those employee are from a given department. So I want to get the data for particular department and select only those SentFromEmployeeId and SentToEmployeeId which belongs to department 100

Comment: @Eldar My Sql query is working fine so want to translate that query in to equivalent linq query. I am having hard time converting that SQL query to equivalent linq

Comment: Can you post the whole query pls. I can't see even some brakets

Comment: @Serge Updated question with final query

Comment: if lr.SentFromEmployeeId || lr.SentToEmployeeId are not nullable then why do you have an Or condition?   It seems like it should be an and.   I am researching if it is possible to have an or linq condition for multiple columns.  so far no luck